# Cannot find namespace angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm developing a Application using `Angular` and `Typescript`. That time i'm facing this error.

```
Error   21  Cannot find namespace 'angular'.
```

How to solve this??

Comment: can you add more context? does it say what cant find the namespace?

Comment: check the order of references

Comment: are you sure you have installed Angular using npm?

Comment: This is definitely Angular installation issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you should add angular types to tsconfig.json as following:

```
  {
...
"compilerOptions":
    ...
    "types": [
        "angular"
    ],
  }
```

If that won't work, since typings are deprecated, I suggest you to install @types/angular with npm:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/angular
```

and include it as above.